# Use of Handler in AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, tcp, android-asynctask, handler

I'm developping an App that uses Wifi/Tcp connection to communicate with a Robot. For the moment I'm using a single thread to manage the tcp connection using a TcpClient class and a "ConnectTask extends AsyncTask" in my MainActivity.

So far this is what I have :

TcpClient.java

```
private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;

private int bufferSize = 5000;
public ByteBuffer bf;
private BufferedInputStream inFromServer;
private BufferedOutputStream outFromClient;
.
.
.
public void run() {

    mRun = true;
    try {
        //here you must put your computer's IP address.
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

        //create a socket to make the connection with the server
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);

        try {
            Log.i("Debug", "inside try catch");

            //receives the message which the server sends back

            inFromServer = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            outFromClient = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());


            bf = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);




            while (mRun) {
               // Log.i("Debug", "inside while mRun");

                bf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                for (int i=0;i<5000;i++) {
                    int b = inFromServer.read();

                    if (b == -1) {
                        break;
                    }

                    bf.put((byte) b);

                }

                if ( bf != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                   // Log.i("Debug","Message received !");
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(bf);
                    mMessageListener.updateBatteryLvl();
                }
                bf.position(0);
            }
        }
.
.
.
```

And this is my ConnectTask in MainActivity :

```
public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<Void, ByteBuffer, TcpClient> {

    @Override
    protected TcpClient doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //we create a TCPClient object and
        mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            //here the messageReceived method is implemented
            public void messageReceived(ByteBuffer message) throws IOException {
                //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                byte[] resultat = new byte[4000];
                resultat = message.array();
                updateBatteryLvl();
                message.clear();
```

I'm not using any Handlers in tcpclient or connecttask, but I have seen some tutorials using them for Tcp Connection and I was wondering why are they using it ? I already tested the connection with the Robot and I receive the data it sends perfectly fine. 
Are Handlers used like semaphores if u have multithreads writing in the same file for exemple ?

Answer (score 0):

> Are Handlers used like semaphores if u have multithreads writing in
>   the same file for exemple ?

More or less, yes.
Handlers can only be created (call its contructor) in a Thread with a Looper (main thread is a thread with a looper).

Then, you can post Runnables and Messages to be run (sometime in the future) by the handler. These runables/messages are enqueued by the hanlder, and dispatched to be run on the thread they were created. So basically, if you run stuff in differente threads, and want to perform some action without worring of race conditions (or need these actions to be run on a specific thread, like when you need to update the UI), you can post "operations" in the handler, and thats all.

In your case, with the AsyncTask, it does the same, doing the work in a separated thread, and commiting the result to the MAIN THREAD. If you need to manage differente threads, and commit the result to single, not MAIN THREAD, you'll need to use a handler.
But as you describe what you're doing, it is no needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do long running operation in the UI thread (main thread) or you'll get ["application not responding"](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html) (ANR).
So you have to use multithreading and Android framework provides infrastructure for easier data synchronization with the main thread (Android UI toolkit is not thread-safe).

Your choice may lead to problems, because:

- AsyncTask should only be used for operations that take quite few seconds.
- AsyncTasks are executed serially on a single background thread (from API 11). So long running worker can block others.
- AsyncTasks do not respect lifecycle of your host Activity (you may get memory leaks).
- Priority in the killing list is [low](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle).